# Flagging comments as useless and for wrong guidance

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderation

Sometimes people are posting comments which are completely wrong as happened, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263741/let-r-mathbbz-x-mathbbqx-find-the-irreducibles-in-r), comment #2, or offering a wrong guidance as happened [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261177/is-it-true-that-rn-simeq-rm-as-rings-implies-m-n#comment2562067_1261177), also comment #2.

If I flag these comments for the above reasons the mods will certainly decline my flags (it happened many times in the past), but these comments are toxic in my opinion, as well for the OP as for the possible future readers. (I know, you can argue that my comments repair this, but I'm not so sure, and even so...)

> Is it possible for the mods to be a little more (mathematically) involved in such cases and delete them?

Comment: *"Moderators are not referees nor editors of the site."* From [an answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731/dont-flag-wrong-answers/4733#4733) in a related discussion. (Although the linked discussion is about mathematically incorrect answers.) Links to some other related discussions on meta can be found there. (See the linked questions.)

Comment: This one seems to be almost a duplicate: [Is it in the Moderator's Job Description to patrol for correctness?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473/is-it-in-the-moderators-job-description-to-patrol-for-correctness)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not think that it is reasonable to expect moderators to act as judges on mathematical correctness or mathematical relevance of some comments.

Even if they certainly could on some occasions it is unreasonable to expect them (or anybody) to be able to do so always; moreover it should also be too time-consuming. There is a large number of flags to be handled.

What you can and should do is what you did: mention your dissenting opinion in a comment notifying OP of comment. If they see their error they might delete the comment or acknowledge the problem. Once it is acknowledged you can consider flagging as "obsolete."